# Modal close jumping to the page bottom

Tags: javascript, c#, model-view-controller, razor, bootstrap-modal

I have a ModalPartial. On page, I'm using HTML5 errors, like min, max length at input boxes.

This page is quite large and the button which triggers the modal popup is at the bottom page.

```
<button type="button"
        class="button"
        asp-route-id="@Model.Id"
        asp-route-culture="@culture"
        data-toggle="modal"
        data-target="#MyModal"
        asp-page-handler="Create">
</button>
```

I found how to "scroll" up, to the input which has an error.

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('input,select,textarea');
var invalidListener = function () { this.scrollIntoView(false); };

for (var i = elements.length; i--;)
    elements[i].addEventListener('invalid', invalidListener);
```

But when I'm hiding the modal, with this code:

```
$("#myModal").modal('hide');
```

The page scroll back to the button which showed the modal. I want to prevent this. I tried the event.preventDefault() but it's doesn't work.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. So when you click the button a modal is displayed if there are errors in the form. You then close the modal and successfully scroll the error (input with error) into view? At what moment then the page is scrolled back to the button that trigger the modal (initial page state)?

Comment: Or is the form within this modal? If you could clarify the steps, we should be able to help.

Comment: Ohh in the modal I has a button which submit the form after scroll to input box, because has error, I want to close the modal to fix the input, but when I close the modal, the page goes back to that button which trigger the modal open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was:

When I check the html errors in javascript, I’m closing the modal too, from code, then doesn’t jump to the bottom page.